# how to avoid text in mobile number field mvc2

Tags: jquery, html

**My code here**

```
<%: Html.TextBox("ContactNumber", Model.ContactNumber, new { @title = "Don't enter 0 or country code before Mobile Number", @maxlength = "10"})%>
```

Here I want to allow only numbers not alphabets. I tried with jquery code.. But I can't catch the result..

**Jquery Code:**

```
$('#ContactNumber').click(function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
 });
```

Please help me to find out the issue?

Comment: you want to allow only numbers then why are you replacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use keydown event instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ContactNumber").keydown(function (e) {
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190]) !== -1 ) {
             return;
        }
        if (((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Also if you use HTML5, you can set the type of input to number

```
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: But it is not allowing backspace and delete operations

Comment: @PoliDev I updated the code to allow common chars like backspace, tab, enter, escape and a decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)  
{  
  var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;  
  if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)){
         return true;  
  } else{  
        alert("message");  
        return false;  
  };  
}
```